# asp.net core api - how to distinguish between `api/cars` and `api/cars?color=red` calls with [FromQuery] object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using `[FromQuery]` atribute in controller's `Get` method:

```cs
//CarsController, etc..
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CarsDto>>> Get([FromQuery] CarsParameter? carsParam = null)
{
    //param is always not null here
}
```

Inside the method I need to distinguish between `api/cars` and `api/cars?color=red` calls. Problem is, that `carsParam` object is never null, so I cannot say if the `Color=""` (defailt value) is intended to be empty string or it's because of the call was `api/cars`

`CarsParameter` is a simple class:

```cs
public class CarsParameter
{
  public string Color {get; set;} = "";
  //more params here
}
```

Yes, I can use different path, like `api/cars/withParams?color=red`, but i am looking for more subtle solution.

Comment: Why don’t you make another endpoint that doesn’t take a cars param , and change this one to a non-nullable parameter?

Comment: @ekke because of: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.` with no extra url change

Comment: try to use this one Get(CarsParameter? carsParam = null, [FromQuery] string color ) -if color is not empty this is from querystring

Comment: @Sergey optional parameters must be on the and.. Also unsupported media type(it doesnt know what CarsParameter is w/out [FromQuery])....

Comment: Ok  this one is the same Get(CarsParameter? carsParam, [FromQuery] string color )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to distinguish between api/cars and api/cars?color=red calls. Problem is, that carsParam object is never null

Please note that default model binding starts by looking through the sources for the key `carsParam.Color`. If that isn't found, it looks for `Color` without a prefix, which cause the issue.

To achieve your requirement, you can try to specify prefix explicitly, like below.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CarsDto>>> Get([FromQuery][Bind(Prefix = "carsParam")] CarsParameter? carsParam = null)
{
```

*Request to `api/cars?color=red&carsParam.color=yellow&carsParam.brand=test`  and following is test result*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me to find what I was looking for. The `Request` variable. Now I can do:  `if(Request.Query.Keys.Any())` => This means it from `api/cars?color=red`, otherwise it's from `api/cars`